# Why is Conda not installing/updating the latest version of Spyder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, spyder

I want to install Spyder on my Anaconda, so I ran the code exactly as instructed here:
https://anaconda.org/anaconda/spyder

```
conda install -c anaconda spyder
```

Running Spyder gave me both:

1. A prompt that says that there is a new version of Spyder
2. An internal error about "Spyder has encountered an internal problem!"

Okay, so I'll try to update Spyder first, and follow the command line instructions here:
https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/installation.html

```
conda update anaconda
conda update spyder
```

Opening Spyder still gave me the same prompt and error. I then checked my Spyder version to be 4.0.1.

Updating everything doesn't seem to help either:

```
conda update --all
```

My Spyder is still version 4.0.1.

Digging further on the error code, supposed "solutions" were given here:
https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/12243
https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/13370
https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/11798

Which is simply to tell users to install the latest version of Spyder by

```
conda install spyder=4.1.*
```

**But those bug reports and "solutions" were made one year ago. Spyder is on later versions now.**

Why is conda still installing Spyder version 4.0.1, with all the issues, one year after 4.0.1 is known to be problematic? Why does it not update correctly to **any** later version? The latest version is supposed to be 5.0.0, with even 4.2.* rolled out before that.

Comment: What did `conda install spyder=4.1.*` (or `spyder=5`) do? It should have given an error if it couldn’t satisfy that. How are you checking versions? `conda list spyder`?

Comment: I didn't want to hard specify the version by doing `conda install spyder=4.1.*` so I didn't do that. During my search, there was a mention that hard specifying "pin" Spyder to the version and hinder future updates. I just want to find out why `conda update spyder` didn't work. I actually checked the version by just clicking Help -> About Spyder in Spyder iteself, which showed 4.0.1. But `conda list spyder` showed 4.0.1 as well.

Comment: And more importantly why is `conda install -c anaconda spyder` still installing version 4.0.1 to being with.

Comment: If there are conflicts (a possible reason why it won’t update), it should find them when running with the hard specification. That can be done as a dry run just to see how it solves it and get some potential insight into what if any packages are in conflict.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I uninstalled Spyder and installed with the line `conda install spyder` instead and Spyder 5.0.0 was successfully installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the Anaconda channel.

I uninstalled Spyder and then install with the line:

```
conda install spyder
```

and Spyder 5.0.0 was successfully installed.

Anaconda's Spyder page (https://anaconda.org/anaconda/spyder) gave the command as:

```
conda install -c anaconda spyder
```

which led to the installation of Spyder 4.0.1, instead of 5.0.0 which was what it was supposed to install as documented on the page itself.

Comment: sekwjlwf - many thanks for the heads up. This is just awesome. I have had exactly the same issue. I now do the same to fix it.