# keeping Spyder updated in Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, spyder

have Anaconda installed on a win-10 box and I am using Spyder 4.1.5

**to sume up**: need to get more insights on how to keep VSCode and Spyder updated .. Can i do that via Conda!? Look forward to hear from you.

well i Would like to update Spyder to the latest version, so I went through the commands:

```
conda update conda
conda update anaconda
conda update spyder
```

They all ran without errors, but the spyder version didn't change - this is command I'm using to launch:

Well - i allways thougth that if we want to update Spyder in the root environment, then the following command conda update spyder works

If we want to update Spyder for a virtual environment we have created (e.g., for a different version of Python), then conda update -n $ENV_NAME spyder where $ENV_NAME is our environment name.

how to indicate what is going on here?

should i run conda update anaconda before updating spyder.

well - i thought that i have to make sure i am in the base directory.

here conda install spyder should work.

I have tried also this: conda install spyder=new_version_number.
new_version_number should be in digits.
[image: see the output]

btw: i had a view on the official docs here: code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging.
In brief, i tried the 'Add Configuration' Button. But i guess i have a screwd up installation &/ configuration.

do i need these steps too!?

- How to activate conda environment in VS code
  https://medium.com/@udiyosovzon/how-to-activate-conda-environment-in-vs-code-ce599497f20d
- Efficient Way to Activate Conda in VSCode
  https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/efficient-way-to-activate-conda-in-vscode-ef21c4c231f2

**update**: its obviousliy the Anaconda-channeling-thing that stands sometimes in the way.  - at  least in regard of spyder-updates

cf.  Why is Conda not installing/updating the latest version of Spyder?
[Why is Conda not installing/updating the latest version of Spyder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67414382/why-is-conda-not-installing-updating-the-latest-version-of-spyder)

> But those bug reports and "solutions" were made one year ago. Spyder
> is on later versions now. Why is conda still installing Spyder version
> 4.0.1, with all the issues, one year after 4.0.1 is known to be problematic? Why does it not update correctly to any later version?
> The latest version is supposed to be 5.0.0, with even 4.2.* rolled out
> before that.
>
> The problem is with the Anaconda channel.
>
> I uninstalled Spyder and then install with the line:
>
> conda install spyder and Spyder 5.0.0 was successfully installed.
>
> Anaconda's Spyder page (https://anaconda.org/anaconda/spyder) gave the
> command as:
>
> conda install -c anaconda spyder which led to the installation of
> Spyder 4.0.1, instead of 5.0.0 which was what it was supposed to
> install as documented on the page itself.

note: i will have a closer look if this behavior is the same - in regard of updating the VSCode!?

update:

i guess that i have to take care for the following steps

```
• Check and test conda is installed and available
• see if i need an Update conda if necessary
• Create the great virtual environment
• Activate a virtual environment - with all the tests that we can apply now
```

**to sume up**: need to get more insights on how to keep VSCode and Spyder updated .. Can i do that via Conda!? Look forward to hear from you.

Comment: conda update spyder should work, maybe state clearly what version of spyder you would expect and then check what version of spyder you can get within conda

Comment: hello dear @Trilarion - many thanks for the comment. I  have to retry this. I guess that i have to enter a certain number /(version) of Spyder in order to get it working. BTW: how it works with VSCode - does VSCode update itselv or do i have to look for these updates not within Anaconda but within the VSCode !?

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio Code has an auto-update for Windows and Mac:
Quote from [vs code faq](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/FAQ):

> ... By default, VS Code is set up to auto-update for macOS and Windows users when we release new updates. If you do not want to get automatic updates, you can set the Update: Mode setting from default to none.
>
> To modify the update mode, go to File > Preferences > Settings (macOS: Code > Preferences > Settings), search for update mode and change the setting to none. ...

Regarding anaconda, your commands seem fine.

```
conda update conda
conda update spyder
```

Should work. Just make sure you have activated your environment.

For more info on conda updates, please refer to [official page](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/update-version/).